# How do I change the PostgreSQL data directory in the OpenGeo Suite 4.5?

Tags: postgresql, boundless-suite

I am using OpenGeo Suite and I would like to move the PostgreSQL databases files to a different drive than my operating system.  The default location installed by OpenGeo Suite is in the "C:\ProgramData\" directory, but I would like for it to be "F:\db\".

Some websites suggest that the data directory location can be changed by adding -D "F:\db\" to the ImagePath value of the PostgreSQL service key in the registry. However, for me this did not change where PostgreSQL is looking, and I have restarted the service several times.  Since OpenGeo customized the service and registry key names, I am afraid that they may have also customized the PostgreSQL service itself to prevent the changing of the data directory.

Does anyone have any knowledge of this?

Comment: Try setting it in postgresql.conf, which is usually in the data directory itself, so you will have to start postgres with a switch for the path to the data directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to force PostgreSQL to use the data folder F:\db\ by creating the following batch file (and manually turning PostgreSQL on/off):

```
start "" /min "C:\<PostregreSQL>\bin\pg_ctl.exe" start -D "F:\db" -w
```

I found this solution here: http://www.garretwilson.com/blog/2014/03/09/postgresql-management-windows.xhtml